# Is this the correct recursive way to write curry function?

Tags: javascript, closures, bind, currying

I can't understand if this recursive curry function is correct or not.

```js
function curry(fn) {
  return function curryInner(...args) {
    if (args.length >= fn.length) return fn(...args);
    return function (...next) {
      return curryInner(...args, ...next);
    };
  };
}

const example = {
  multiplier: 5,
  calculate: function (a, b) {
    return (a + b) * this.multiplier;
  },
};
example.curriedVersion = curry(example.calculate);

console.log(example.calculate(1, 2));
console.log(example.curriedVersion(1)(2));
```

I have curry function implement with binding but I am not sure why it works and recursive does not. Can you help me to understand this, I think my context understanding in this functions is incorrect

```
function curry(func) {
    return function curried(...args) {

        if (args.length >= func.length) {
            return func.apply(this, args)
        } else {
            return curried.bind(this, ...args)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which part are you confused about?

Comment: "*I cant understand if this recursive curry function is correct or not.*" If the result of currying with this function is wrong, then the curry function is wrong. Why exactly are you not convinced of that?

Comment: I dont understand why it is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curring is correct, the problem is with `this.multiplier`.

When you use the expression `example.calculate` without calling the function, it doesn't bind `this`. So `this.multiplier` will be `undefined`.

Use `example.calculate.bind(example)` and your currying will work as expected.

```js
function curry(fn) {
  return function curryInner(...args) {
    if (args.length >= fn.length) return fn(...args);
    return function (...next) {
      return curryInner(...args, ...next);
    };
  };
}

const example = {
  multiplier: 5,
  calculate: function (a, b) {
    return (a + b) * this.multiplier;
  },
};
example.curriedVersion = curry(example.calculate.bind(example));

console.log(example.calculate(1, 2));
console.log(example.curriedVersion(1)(2));
```

Comment: as a follow up, can i ask why we use apply in a second implementation?

Comment: `apply()` is the old way before spread syntax was added in ES6.